# Label polyline with vertex numbers

Tags: qgis, labeling, symbology, vertices, count

In QGIS 3.4.8 I can label vertices with their vertex number by using the following expression for a Font marker symbol:

@geometry_point_num

But, the expression only seems to count the vertices within the current view - so as I zoom in and out the numbers change.

Is there a way to make this work for each whole polyline, irrespective of the view, so the numbers do not change?  So I can, for example, zoom into a line and know I am looking at the fifth vertex along the line.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For me, what you want works with the expression `@geometry_part_num` . In the layer-styling, I set the style to be rendered by geometry-generator with the expression  `nodes_to_points( $geometry)`. As a marker, I select Font-marker and at the selection of the symbol, I select data-driven override with the expression `@geometry_part_num`

Comment: !*!*!..PerFectO..!*!*!

Comment: Screenshots in this answer helped me a lot : https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/328386/20843

Answer (score 1):

You could [extract the vertices of the line](https://wiki.tuflow.com/index.php?title=QGIS_Convert_Lines_to_Points) as point using the extract nodes tool.  And  the point to your project.  [Add a new attribute to the table with a sequence of numbers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27739/filling-column-with-consecutive-numbers-in-qgis).  Label those points using the sequence.