QGIS Labels: Accessing Values that were created in the Geometry Generator as MultPointM
I have a  LineStringM layer, and needed to create a kind of river mileage.
Therefore I was using the geometry generator in the Label-Tab.
So far I was able to get the MultiPointM, but can not access any m-Information out of these. Unfortunately creating a seperate Layer would be no option in the project.
Current State:

Desired State:


If you want to label each vertex with M value you may find inspiration from these question : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/334469/label-polyline-with-vertex-numbers , https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/381114/displaying-vertex-coordinates-of-polygon-or-line-without-creating-new-layer-in-q , https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/381187/convert-vertices-of-polygon-features-to-points-using-virtual-layer-in-qgis/381247#381247

Thanks so much!
