# Getting rid of vertices of polyline (or polygon) using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis

I need to know the ID (or name) of vertices of a polyline (or polygon) to build someting like this image.

[image]

As the tread below I already used @geometry_point_num command to have vertex's ID but it return only the number of the vertex on screen and that's not useful for me because I have some km long polyline.

[How to get or assign vertex id to polygon vertices and use these as vertex label using pyqgis?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/215990/how-to-get-or-assign-vertex-id-to-polygon-vertices-and-use-these-as-vertex-label/328386)

That's no good because I need to take absolute ID of vertex like I can show on vertex editing

[image]

In that way I can extract as label text the angle value of the id vertex.

For have the angle value I use something like that:

[image]

I suppose that using the function editor I can get it but I don't know Python and QGIS library.

I also considered to extract the vertex points or subdivide my polyline to lines but that's not useful for my scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution looking at this site: https://issues.qgis.org/issues/21109

By default I have "clip features" checked.

[image]

This function apply a limit of calcs to only the objects (or part of them) on the screen. So disabling this I solved.

To obtain something like the image attached

[image]

I used a simble composed like this

[image]

Where the first character simbol is the name ov vertices:

```
    if( 
(@geometry_point_num - 1) = 0 
or abs(degrees(azimuth( point_n($geometry,   @geometry_point_num), point_n($geometry,  @geometry_point_num + 1))) - degrees(azimuth( point_n($geometry,  @geometry_point_num - 1), point_n($geometry,@geometry_point_num )))) < 1
or (@geometry_point_num = num_points($geometry)), 
'P',
'V')  ||   (@geometry_point_num - 1)
```

The second is the deviation angle

the text

```
to_dms(
if(
if (abs(degrees(azimuth( point_n($geometry,   @geometry_point_num), point_n($geometry,  @geometry_point_num + 1))) - degrees(azimuth( point_n($geometry,  @geometry_point_num - 1), point_n($geometry,  @geometry_point_num ))))<1, 
null,
if(degrees(azimuth( point_n($geometry,   @geometry_point_num), point_n($geometry,  @geometry_point_num + 1))) < degrees(azimuth( point_n($geometry,  @geometry_point_num - 1), point_n($geometry,  @geometry_point_num ))),
degrees(azimuth( point_n($geometry,  @geometry_point_num - 1), point_n($geometry,  @geometry_point_num ))) - degrees(azimuth( point_n($geometry,   @geometry_point_num), point_n($geometry,  @geometry_point_num + 1))),
degrees(azimuth( point_n($geometry,   @geometry_point_num), point_n($geometry,  @geometry_point_num + 1))) - degrees(azimuth( point_n($geometry,  @geometry_point_num - 1), point_n($geometry,  @geometry_point_num )))))>90,
90,
if (abs(degrees(azimuth( point_n($geometry,   @geometry_point_num), point_n($geometry,  @geometry_point_num + 1))) - degrees(azimuth( point_n($geometry,  @geometry_point_num - 1), point_n($geometry,  @geometry_point_num ))))<1, 
null,
if(degrees(azimuth( point_n($geometry,   @geometry_point_num), point_n($geometry,  @geometry_point_num + 1))) < degrees(azimuth( point_n($geometry,  @geometry_point_num - 1), point_n($geometry,  @geometry_point_num ))),
degrees(azimuth( point_n($geometry,  @geometry_point_num - 1), point_n($geometry,  @geometry_point_num ))) - degrees(azimuth( point_n($geometry,   @geometry_point_num), point_n($geometry,  @geometry_point_num + 1))),
degrees(azimuth( point_n($geometry,   @geometry_point_num), point_n($geometry,  @geometry_point_num + 1))) - degrees(azimuth( point_n($geometry,  @geometry_point_num - 1), point_n($geometry,  @geometry_point_num ))))))
, 'x', 2)
```

the rotation angle of text (is the same for the line under this angle)

```
degrees( azimuth( point_n($geometry,   @geometry_point_num -1), point_n($geometry,  @geometry_point_num ))) + 4
```

For that rotation angle, I don't know why, I must correct the value adding an angle that is near to 4°. Whithout that correction, graphically, I can't see that object in right position also the vaue of the expression without the correction is already right.

Answer (score 0):

Using Qgis Python, you can find the closestVertex and its vertexId.

```
line_geom.closestSegmentWithContext(QgsPointXY(point))
```

closestSegmentWithContext returns the vertext_distance, closestVertex, vertexId and direction of the point (the point you placed is right or left of the line geometry).

here +1 means point place is right to the line geometry (look from start point of line) and -1 is left of line. For a line geometry Vertex id starts with 0.