# Labeling line Nodes with m and z values in QGIS

Tags: qgis

Is there a way to label the nodes of line features with the z and m values using QGIS?

Answer (score 2):

Insert an expression for the label value: `m($geometry)` respectively `z($geometry)`.

Edit answer: for lines/polygons use menu vector -> geometry tools -> extract vertices. You get a new layer with the vertices. Now, you can label this as described above. Set the symbol styling to no symbol to hide the extracted vertices and to show only the labels.

Comment: This doesn't work. It's fine for labeling points. But not lines, or nodes on lines.

Comment: Edited answer. You could also try to construct an expression on the line-layer, using    the expression nodes_to_points( ( $geometry)) to create a multipoint geometry from the nodes. However, I'm not sure how to achieve different labeling for each of them - maybe for this, open a new question. I guess however that the solution proposed above is easier, but envolves creating a new layer.

Comment: Is there a way of adding a virtual layer to extract the vertices? I was after something that would update more dynamically than clicking around the geometry tools....

Comment: Does this suit for what you want to do? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/215990/how-to-get-or-assign-vertex-id-to-polygon-vertices-and-use-these-as-vertex-label/328386