# Multi line string labeling QGIS

Tags: qgis

I was wondering if there is any way to achieve the following in QGIS; by drawing a single line.

[image]

Having the sections of line between the points labeled up in an ascending order automatically;  ideally I'd like to be able to do this many times on the same layer so say for example I could have 10 different lines, with 5 points each meaning I'd have 10 different lines labeled up the exact same way.

Comment: If you have a follow up question then that should be asked as a new question. You can link to this one as part of the background to why you are asking it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can easily be done using multiple styling levels.

1. Simple Line
2. Marker Line with a simple Marker which is placed on `every vertex`
   [image]
3. Marker Line with a Font Marker which is placed on `central points of segments` using `@geometry_point_num` as an expression for the `Character(s)` property.
   [image]
   [image]

Result:
[image]

If your `LineString` has a lot of points in corners you can use a `Geometry Generator` at the top level of your symbology and use an expression like `simplify( $geometry, 50)` which will

"Simplifies a geometry by removing nodes using a distance based threshold (ie, the Douglas Peucker algorithm). The algorithm preserves large deviations in geometries and reduces the number of vertices in nearly straight segments."

[image]

All other style levels then need to be under the geometry and can be used as described above.

As you can see in the result even though the line has multiple points in the corner it is simplified to one single point and the segments are labeled accordingly.

Important to note: For the `Geometry Generator` to work, your CRS needs to have meters as unit.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Based on [Saijin_Naib answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/215990/getting-or-assigning-vertex-id-to-polygon-vertices-and-use-these-as-vertex-label/328386#328386) you may :

1. add a marker line on top of your line and select "On first vertex"
   and "On inner vertices"
2. choose a font marker as symbol
3. use data defined override on the character symbol using
   `@geometry_point_num`
4. Offset the Font marker X position to put it next to the vertices (as
   each segment may have a different length you wont be able to put the
   number in the middle of the segment, if you offset to much the
   number may go over the next segment....)

(In the below picture I add a second marker line as red circle to show the vertices position, the "on last vertex" option is also used for this)

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use this algorithm. And you can choose distance.
[image]