# Automatically populate road section every km

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

I really don't know how to do this or if it's possible.
I have separated in a layer a section of a motorway. The attribute table only has 1 line, the total length.
I need to populate the table in a way that I get a new row per km, so I can then add a label each km

Comment: If your end goal is to add label at each km this could help you https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/442113/multi-line-string-labeling-qgis/

Answer (score 5):

QGIS has tools that allow you to split lines into measured segments.  See [Splitting lines into equal segments with QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/85415/115) for more information.

If your need is to only have labels every km then you should consider using the label placement tools in QGIS to place labels every 1000 map units (assuming your data use UTM coordinates).

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[Split lines by maximum length](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgissplitlinesbylength) does exactly what you want.

> This algorithm takes a line (or curve) layer and splits each feature
> into multiple parts, where each part is of a specified maximum length.

[image]