# Automatically label vertices of a selected polygon in QGIS 3 Map composer

Tags: pyqgis, shapefile, print-composer, vertices, geometry-generator

I am looking at how to automate my repetitive tasks.
So How can I automate the labeling of vertices of selected plot in QGIS3? And is it possible to have all the labels outside the polygon? See image below. I would like to add labels for the highlighted polygon (486) starting with 'a' up to 'd' so that they relate to a coordinate table.

[image]

Comment: There are too many stuffs that can distract the readers from understanding your actual problem. Kindly edit the question and focus more on the labelling problem. Provide some examples or share a demo data.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: This answer may be helpful: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/215990/getting-or-assigning-vertex-id-to-polygon-vertices-and-use-these-as-vertex-label?rq=1